# Changing the background of a Collapsing Toolbar

Tags: android

I have a Collapsing toolbar in my `ProfileFragment.java`.
I want to change it's background using Glide, so the user can change it the way they like it. Like they would change a normal banner picture. Can I do that?
Here is my XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/testeparabackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="203dp">


    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/backgroundcollapsedtoolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed|scroll"
        android:background="@drawable/banner_profile"
        app:title="Feel">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

***EDIT***

I don't know if I was clear enough so, here is an edit. I want that big grey block to change it's background image when the user loads an image from their gallery. I already know how to get the image from gallery, I just don't know  **how to load it into the collapsing toolbar** [image: Click here, please]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, then you should add the image into the CollapsingToolbarLayout with whatever collapsemode creates the effect you want. So it would look like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/testeparabackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="203dp">


    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/backgroundcollapsedtoolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed|scroll"
        android:background="@drawable/banner_profile"
        app:title="Feel">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarimage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" 
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the answer. I've tried that already but, somehow, my imageview got "invisible". The standard image that it had disappeared and now I can't seem to add a background to it...

Comment: And right now I've tried to load an image from the gallery and the images loads and in one second it disappears xd

Comment: @MatarUano Are you still using Glide to try to do this?

Comment: Yup `Glide.with(getContext()).load(imageUri).centerCrop().into(imgFotoCapa);`

Comment: @MatarUano I would recommend first trying to do it without Glide just to see if maybe something with the centercrop or loading is an issue.

Comment: I could try that but I bet that that isn't the problem. I've tried to change the image manually in the XML file and in android studio `design mode` the imageview is still invisible

Comment: What I mean is, the ImageView is supposed to start with a standard image and it won't start :P

Comment: @MatarUano I have updated my answer with the way I did it in a different app that worked, try that.